# Swing JDialog suspend when I press windows+d

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, suspend

There's a window Named A and when I click one button, Dialog B will popup and then I click a button on dialog B, B will hide, and at this time a calculation will process and Window A will appear. And after calculate finished, Dialog C will appear.  But when I press Windows + D to show the desktop before the dialog C show, then the dialog will suspend and I must kill the process by task manager.  All the dialogs here are modal.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) All GUI updates should be performed on the Event Dispatch Thread.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't reproduce the problem use MCVE. May be I can't find the key point.

Comment: Start from the fact there must be a difference between your MCVE and the actual code.  Start putting things into the MCVE, so it is like your main code, until the MCVE shows the same problem.  That should help vastly narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: Have you defined window `A` as parent of Dialog `C`. Do you use  `SwingWorker` to do your calculation? +1 for an MCVE btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the parent window in the constructor of a `JDialog`. Moreover you could specifiy the dialog as modal to prevent any interaction with the parent window while the dialog is open. Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame);
    dialog.setSize(200,200);
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
    dialog.setModal(true);  // Works also with .setModal(false)
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I have set both parent window and the dialog window as modal. I think that is not the point. Because if I didn't press windows+d, everything go normally. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Can you please run the sample code from my edited post? Which OS are you using?

Comment: I use Windows7. Sorry that I haven't describe the question particularly and I have edit again. Please read it again if you have time, many thanks.